# Dynamic enums in vb6

Tags: vb6

Is there a way to create an enum at runtime in vb6?
Basically I need to create a enum of Products, but I'll get the data of Products at runtime and this is supposed to vary.

Answer (score 6):

No.

The whole point of enums is to provide type safety at compile time. For example, if a function accepts an enum value as a parameter, the range of valid inputs is well-defined based on the members of the enum type. It doesn't have to worry about how to handle invalid input because that will result in a compiler error.

There's no way to achieve this kind of type safety at run time, so dynamically created enums don't make much sense. At any rate, they're not a feature supported by the language or runtime environment.

You'll have to just use a unique identifier (like a string or a numeric value) in place of an enum. If you wanted, you could create an array or another collection class that mapped those IDs to a unique key (e.g., the name of product). You could then add products to the array dynamically at runtime, and retrieve their ID by name.

Note that with this strategy, you will need to validate inputs and handle any errors manually.

Comment: +1 but in VB6 there's no compiler check on values passed to a routine expecting an Enum. And no run-time check either :(

Comment: @MarkJ Nuts, really? Thanks for the correction. I guess that's not so surprising, C and C++ have the same behavior. At any rate, I'm starting to wonder if it's been far too long since I actually used VB 6 for any production code to be answering questions with that tag. :-/